# Не работают в php post переменные со скобками: []

Tags: post, php

```
<input type="checkbox" name="var[]"/>
```

Речь идет про переменные из html-форм, которые можно использовать как массивы.
[Страница из мануала пхп](http://php.net/manual/ru/faq.html.php#faq.html.select-multiple)

На локалхосте работает, а когда залил на сервер - не работает, передает пустое значение вместо массива. Это какая-то настройка в пхп?

Comment: А вы используете массивы вида $_POST или $_GET? Может вся причина, что вы не забыли _ после $.

Comment: не, ничего не забыл. Если б забыл, на локалхосте бы не работало.

Comment: Почему, должен работать, а обработчик как принимает POST, типа так?
if($_POST['name']=='name'){

} вариантов много, возможно хостинге проблемы?

Comment: $ids=array();
foreach($_POST['ids'] as $v)$ids[]=(int)$v;
$ids=array_unique($ids);

А в хтмл-коде такое:

<input type="checkbox" name="ids[]" value="1"/>

<input type="checkbox" name="ids[]" value="2"/>

<input type="checkbox" name="ids[]" value="3"/>

Comment: А если $_POST['ids']  присвоить например к $ids_p = $_POST['ids']; потом работать с этой переменной?

Comment: так а разница какая =) всеравно там пустое значение

Answer (score 2):

```
<form action="" name="someForm">

<input type="text" name="someForm[testInput]">

<?php
    echo $_POST['someForm']['testInput']
?>
```

а так пробовали?